# Ajax не срабатывает для подгруженной формы

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте.

Есть кнопка, по клику на которую вызывается событие `loadBlock()` :

```
  function loadBlock(block){
      $('#blockplace').html('<center><h3>Загрузка</h3><img src = "/img/load.gif"></center>');
      var msg = 'method=getblock&block='+block;
      alert(msg);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data: msg,

          success: function(data) {
            $('#blockplace').html(data);
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
    }
```

В результате подгружаются различные формы.

Но, для них почему то не срабатывает ajax.

Код ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#form").submit(function(){ 
    preloader();
    var form = $(this); 
    var error = false;
    form.find('input, textarea').each( function(){
      if ($(this).val() == '') { 
        $('#response').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Все поля обязательны для заполнения! </div>'); 
        /*
          <div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Ошибка!</strong>'+$(this).attr('placeholder')+' </div>
        */
        error = true; 
      }
    });
    if (!error) { 
      var data = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST', 
         url: 'ajax.php', 
        // dataType: 'json', 
         data: data, 
           beforeSend: function(data) { 
                form.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
              },
           success: function(data){ 
              if (data['error']) { 
                $('#response').html(data); 
              } else { 
                $('#response').html(data); 
              }
             },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                alert(xhr.status); 
                alert(thrownError); 
             },
           complete: function(data) { 
                form.find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false); 
             }

           });
    }
    return false; 
  });
});
```

В чем может быть проблема? Консоль совершенно пуста.

Форма:

```
<form id = "formfromajax" align = "center">
<p id = "response"></p>
<p>Введите ключ:</p>

<p><input type = "text" name = "key" id = "key"></p>
<input type = "hidden" name = "method" value = "key">
<button type = "submit" class= "btn btn-primary noty">Проверить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Проблема в том что на момент совершения события `document.ready` ваших форм в DOM нет. Поэтому к ним не биндится никаких обработчиков. Читайте про `on` или `live` методы в jquery api.

Comment: В коде формы id один, а в JS другой. Сделайте его одинаковым

Comment: @lolbas, код аякса тот же, только из другого проекта, поэтому иды не совпадают. 

А так все ID те, которые надо

Comment: Ага! Если код формы 1 в 1, то вот проблема: не указан метод передачи данных(GET, POST, ...)

Comment: @lolbas
`  type: 'POST', ` - указано же.

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно сказал @u_mulder, к загруженой форме не были привязаны события на момент `document.ready`, т.к. таких идентефикаторов еще не существовало. Для того, чтобы ваш код работал, необходимо заменить

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
...
});
```

на код, с использованием [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(){
...
});
```

Исходя из кода формы, который вы добавили, ошибка в том, что у формы нет атрибута `method`, а значит данные не передаются по тому протоколу, к которому вы обращаетесь в обработчике. Нужно добавить `method="post"` в тег `<form>`.

Стоит отметить, что `$("#form").on('submit', function(){ ... });` работать не будет, т.к. `#form` еще не создана.

---

Метод [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) является устаревшим начиная с версии jQuery 1.7, а с 1.9 метод был удален.

Comment: Внимательно: с 1.7 он считался deprecated, в 1.9 был удалён.

Comment: тьфу, точно, исправляюсь

Comment: @lolbas и как тогда можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: @ВиталийRS способом, который описан в моем ответе. `.live` там не используется, а `.on` самое то

Comment: @lolbas, сейчас попробую

Comment: @lolbas, форма отправляется, но теперь не отрабатывает `serialize()` для таких форм.

Comment: @lolbas честно, не много не понял.

Comment: @ВиталийRS проверил на деле, в вашем и моем случае `this` возвращает кликнутый объект.. в консоли ошибок нет?

Comment: @lolbas, консоль вообще ничего не возворащает. 

Т.е. форма нормально отправляется, но без данных вообще.

Comment: @ВиталийRS при пустых полях ошибка появляется? Добавьте код формы в свой вопрос, может ошибка там

Comment: @lolbas добавил форму в пост. 

Только вряд ли проблема в ней, она ж отправляется, только данные оттуда не уходят.

Comment: Все нормально в таком виде работает, $(this) возвращает форму, $(this).serialize возвращает данные: http://jsfiddle.net/tawxktt1/